# "Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras"

Tags: apt

After I did a clean installation of Ubuntu today, not a single package instalation is working. when I type;

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

It says;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Same goes for vlc and every package I try to install.

Comment: Enable additional repositories using the steps given in the question linked above.

Answer (score 0):

type

> sudo apt-get update

& hit enter. after this wait 1-2 minutes. then type your commands.

OR

login as superuser

> sudo su

and type your commands.